# How to commit SQLite3 updates on PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite3 in PHP, and everithing was fine until I needed to perform an UPDATE.
I supose I miss a COMMIT, but I don't find the way on how to do it.

My code is:

```
$respostes = $_POST['respostes'];
$return = array();

$conn = new SQLite3( '/home/pi/boxberry/boxberry.db', SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE );

$res = $conn->query( 'SELECT numero, resposta FROM preguntes WHERE NOT correcta' );
while( $resposta = $res->fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC ) )
{
    if( strstr( strtolower( $respostes ), strtolower( $resposta['resposta'] ) ) !== FALSE )
    {
        $conn->exec( 'UPDATE preguntes SET correcta = 1 WHERE numero = ' . $resposta['numero'] );
        $return['canvis'] = $conn->changes();
        $conn->exec( 'COMMIT' );
        $res = $conn->query( 'SELECT correcta FROM preguntes WHERE numero = ' . $resposta['numero'] );
        $tmp = $res->fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC );
        $return['tmp'] = $tmp['correcta'];
    }
}

.... more stuff ...

echo json_encode( $return );
```

What I want is to read all the questions from the database, and compare the answers from the `resposta` column with the answers within the `$respostes` variable received by POST. That also works fine.
Then, if the answer is correct, I need to put this correctness to the database, setting the `correcta` column for this row to 1.
If I show the query and then I put it on the SQLite3 console it works properly, but when I recheck it on PHP it keeps being 0, even when `$conn->changes()` shows that the UPDATE affected 1 row.

I checked everithing I can figure, the boxberry.db file is readable and writable by any user, I tried oppening it with SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE that should be as default, I tried to add an execution of a COMMIT, or even put it in the same exec line sepparating both with semicolons... No error is thrown, but the values doesn't change.

Using SQLite with Python I found that I need to COMMIT after the UPDATE, but I can't find the way to do it in PHP.

This script returns something like:
{"canvis":1,"tmp":0}
That means it should be 1 change, but then the value in the database is still 0 when should be 1.

Comment: PDO is probably easier and is more portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to manually commit changes with the `SQLite3` extension but you might need to make the directory that contains the database file writable (probably set it so that your webserver software has write-rights). Just making the database file itself writable is not always enough for SQLite.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using PDO for this rather than the SQLite3 extension:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/home/pi/boxberry/boxberry.db');

$res = $dbh->query('SELECT numero, resposta FROM preguntes WHERE NOT correcta');
foreach($res as $resposta)
{
  if(FALSE !== strstr(strtolower($respostes), strtolower($resposta['resposta'])))
  {
    $updstmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE preguntes SET correcta = 1 WHERE numero = :numero');
    $updstmt->bindParam(':numero', $resposta['numero']);
    $updstmt->execute();
    $return['canvis'] = $updstmt->rowCount();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT correcta FROM preguntes WHERE numero = :numero');
    $stmt->bindParam(':numero', $resposta['numero']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $return['tmp'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
}
```

*This is untested, but should work as a drop-in replacement for the OP's sample code.*

By using PDO, you don't have to concern yourself with commit statements in SQLite as they are handled automatically. If you **want** the ability to commit or rollback for a specific set of queries, you can use [`PDO::beginTransaction`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.begintransaction.php) and `commit()`/`rollBack()`.

Comment: Thank you for the code @Justin, but I ended using SQLite3 itself, what I missed was the directory permissions rather than only the database file ones.