# Rows are not adding in the Sqlite Database Table

Tags: php, sqlite

I am unable to add rows to my Sqlite table from my web page and surprisingly its not throwing an exception as well . When I am trying to add the data from sql query its going in the the table.

Its printing **insert done in Persons table** , but no data is inserted.

```
try {
    $q1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO persons(person_id,person_name,User_Id,Profile_Pair_Id,CallType_no,Home_Floor,Start_Date,End_Date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $q1->execute(array($person_id,$name,$uid,$pc,$ct,$Home_Floor, $Start_Dt,$End_Dt));
    echo 'insert done in Persons table'. '<br>';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message while inserting in Persons table: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Have you searched around for this error, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007382/how-to-commit-sqlite3-updates-on-php)?  You shouldn't have to commit the insert, but there are a few other stones to turn here.

Comment: Please, refer to a manual http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php, `execute` method has __no parameters__. It does __not throw__ exception either.

Comment: @u_mulder , I have referred http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @tim biegeleisen, Yes I have checked there ...but could not find a solution :-(

Comment: If you use PDO - then why do you set tag `sqlite3`?

Comment: @u_mulder, sorry my bad...